# Blowing up families of singular curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, blowup

I am stuck with a simple example, but I guess the more general question would be whether blow ups commute with restrictions to subsets (points) of the blow-up locus.

Over $\mathbb{C}$, suppose that $\pi: X \rightarrow C$ is a family of singular (say, nodal) curves on $X$ parametrized by some smooth curve $C$. Suppose also that the singular locus of all fibers $X_c, c \in C$ is a curve $D$ on $X$.
If I blow up $X$ along $D$, is every fiber of $\operatorname{Bl}_DX \rightarrow X \rightarrow C$ the blow up of $X_c$ along its singular point?

The example I looked at was the trivial family of nodal cubics $E \times \mathbb{A}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$, where $E$ is $y^2 = x^3+x^2$. Here - using coordinates $x, y, t$ - I wanted to blow up the total space along $\mathbb{A}^1 = V(x, y)$, which precisely contains the nodes of all fibers. I am stuck at describing the blow up and its fibers explicitly (rather, my computations don't end up with something sensible). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Interesting title! Be careful when [talking about this topic out loud](http://mathoverflow.net/a/53738/35610). :-)

Comment: I've been googling topics like this for days, and at times it did actually make me feel a little uneasy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This is more of a comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet.)

The basic problem is that blowing up is typically something you do to a subset of codimension *two*. (OK, there are subtleties involving blowing up non-Cartier divisors, but that's not what's going on here.)

But in your example, the fibres $X_c$ and the total space $X$ have singularities in codimension *one*. So to resolve the singularities, you should *normalize* first. The question is then whether the normalization of $X$ resolves each fibre. In your example, the answer is clearly *yes*. One could imagine more complicated examples, though, where the general fibre has several singular points which collide on the special fibre. In such a case I don't know what could happen.

Comment: Thank you, that's an observation that didn't occur to me. In fact, this should solve the more complicated examples that I'm considering, because normalization can be done locally and every family I consider more or less looks like this. I will work through some details and then accept this answer.

Comment: You're welcome.